# Electrical cable getting warm

Tags: electrical, heating, appliances

I have an oil filled radiant heater that is several years old. I've tried it in multiple electrical outlets and the electrical cable on it gets hot close to the end that gets plugged in. It also feels like the cable is more pliable close to where it's getting hot. Is there anything I can do about this or is it a problem? I do use the heater everyday and I don't have much money to buy a new one at the moment so I'd prefer not to throw it out.

Comment: OP: "It must be the electrical outlets problem, I bought a new heater and still I feel its connection cord getting warm." It's not uncommon for electrical heater's cords to run hot. See Wolf's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only getting hot at the plug end and not along the rest of the cord then the plug itself may not be getting a good connection at the outlet.

This causes a high resistance connection which generates heat when current is drawn by the heater.

Make sure the prongs on the plug are clean and make a good connection with the outlet. Try the plug in a brand new receptacle if you have one or a new power strip. If the plug is worn and feels loose in the outlet then you could replace the cord cap with a new one.

Also, this could be a problem with older receptacles that are worn out. In older homes the receptacles get sloppy and cords can be inserted and removed too easily. This also creates a high resistance connection. With a small load like a lamp, it is not as much of a problem, but with a heater that draws high current it can become more of an issue. The solution here is to replace the receptacles.

Comment: **Do not** plug electric heaters into a power strip or extension cord.

Comment: I didn't mean that they should use a heater for an extended period in a power strip or extension cord. Only to test the plug for a good tight fit. But if a power strip or extension cord is rated for 15 amps there would be nothing wrong with that either. Heaters sold in the US cannot exceed 1500 watts (which is really 1440 watts, 12 amps times 120 volts, but they let the manufacturers market them as 1500 watts.)

Comment: Most user manuals specifically mention not to use heaters with extension cords/power strips.

Comment: It's very possible the wire near the rigid end that's connected to the plug is in the process of becoming broken (i.e. some strands of a multi-strand wire are broken). Where the wire enters the plug and transitions from the bendy wire to the rigid plug is a bad spot for this to happen. Usually, there is some strain relief to help, but over time, it could be failing. The result is exactly as for a poor connection to the receptacle: "This causes a high resistance connection which generates heat when current is drawn by the heater.".

Comment: And, I should add that if that's not fixed, it's a possible fire hazard...

Comment: It must be the electrical outlets problem, I bought a new heater and still I feel its connection cord getting warm.

Answer (score 0):

Is the entire cord heating uniformly, or is one particular spot (e.g.  the plug) getting notably warmer than the rest?  **Hotspots are Very Bad.** Replacement plugs are about $4. Replacement outlets are about 75 cents.

But if it is merely a case of the entire cord being slightly warm, that could simply be the manufacturer using the thinnest wire allowed (e.g. 14 ga for 12 amps continuous).  That will get warm and will waste energy, but the rules are only there to prevent fires or burned skin.

Comment: Maybe this goes without saying, but you cut the cord just before where it has the hotspot, not just the plug.